# Ошибка в AngularJS. В чем проблема?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Подскажите, где я ошибся в данном коде? Почему ng-controller отказывается работать? Спасибо заранее.

```js
var testapp = angular.module("testapp", []);
testapp.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    'name': 'Aleh',
    'surname': 'Sokolovskuy'
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="testapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in users">
      <p>{{users.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете не ту переменную в шаблоне: `users` вместо `name`:

```js
var testapp = angular.module("testapp", []);
testapp.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    'name': 'Aleh',
    'surname': 'Sokolovskuy'
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="testapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in users">
      <p>{{name.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, проявил невнимательность.